# Get GalleryView or ListView from a custom BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, galleryview

Is there a way to simply get the `GalleryView` or `ListView` that is using my custom adapter?

The reason for this is because i want to initialize the `onItemClicks` from within my `custom adapter`.

I can get the items child views but i don't know how i can get the `ListView` or `GalleryView` that is displaying and using my `custom adapter`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jonney refer to this tutorial which shows the galleryview by using custom baseadpater class
may this'll help you.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html